# Unique constraint in XML Schema

Tags: xml, schema, unique, constraints

Let's say I have following XML file:

```
<authors>
   <author>a1</author>
   <author>a2</author>
   <lastmodified>2010</lastmodified>
</authors>
```

and an XML schema fragment:

```
<xs:element name="authors" maxOccurs="1">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="author" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"> </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="lastmodified" type="xs:date" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:unique name="uniqueAuthor">
     <xs:selector xpath="."/>
     <xs:field xpath="author"/>
  </xs:unique>
</xs:element>
```

What I want is to make a constraint that will not allow two identical author values, but the one above doesn't work that way. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `selector` XPath selects the nodes that must be unique (in that case, it should select the author nodes).

The `field` XPath selects what "makes them unique" (in that case, using `.` will cause their typed value, in that case the text between the tags, treated as a string, to be used).

The document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<authors>
  <author>a1</author>
  <author>a2</author>
  <lastmodified>2010-01-01</lastmodified>
</authors>
```

should be valid against the following schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="authors">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="author" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="lastmodified" type="xs:date" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="uniqueAuthor">
      <xs:selector xpath="author"/>
      <xs:field xpath="."/>
    </xs:unique>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

while this one should not:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<authors>
  <author>a1</author>
  <author>a1</author>
  <lastmodified>2010-01-01</lastmodified>
</authors>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use type="xs:ID" on the author element. There is also type IDREF for referring to an ID.

Comment: Uniqueness constraints have some advantages over `xs:ID`, see http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/11/20/schemas.html#identity_constraints