# Unique element in XSD schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm writing a xml schema. I want some node to be unique based upon some inner element. I wrote the below schema but it is not working. I am able to add same book/employee more than once. I want my book name/employee is should be unique and through exception if someone enters duplicate element(node)
can someone help me in this? Thanks in advance.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com" targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com" elementFormDefault="unqualified">

<xs:complexType name="employee">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="employees">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="employees" type="employee" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:unique name="uniqueId">
                <xs:selector xpath="employee"/>
                <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
            </xs:unique>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="book">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="author" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="title" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="bookList">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="bookList" type="book" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:unique name="uniqueBook">
                <xs:selector xpath="book"/>
                <xs:field xpath="@title"/>
            </xs:unique>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="Library">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="bookList" type="bookList"/>
            <xs:element name="employees" type="employees"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Can you post a sample xml please?

Comment: Why haven't you accepted answers to any of the 20 questions you've asked?

Comment: @jayvee <ns2:Library xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3schools.com">
    <bookList>
        <bookList author=“author1” title=“title1”/>
        <bookList author=“author2” title=“title2”/>
        <bookList author=“author3” title=“title1”/>
   </bookList>
    <employees>
        <employees name=“employee1” id=“id1”/>
        <employees name=“employee2” id=“id2”/>
        <employees name=“employee3” id=“id2”/>
   </employees>
</ns2:Library>

Answer (score 0):

Your schema says that the `id` attribute of `employee` elements must be unique, but both in your schema and in your instance (posted as a comment), the `employee` element does not have an id attribute; instead it has a `title` attribute.

Furthermore, your `employee` and `book` elements are declared in the schema to be in a namespace (though this namespace is missing from your instance), and you have ignored this namespace in defining your selector/field XPath expressions in your uniqueness constraints.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to try and debug code with known typos. Do us the courtesy of getting your question right.

Comment: I know issue is relate to selector/field xpath. can you help me in this? I'm new to this thing.

Comment: I followed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717515/unique-constraint-in-xml-schema 
for my case book should be unique based upon book' title. thats why selector xpath is book and field xpath is title