# XML Schema unique constraint not recognised in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, xsd, xsd-validation

After trying a lot of things to get an error in IntelliJ over a unique constraint I'm starting to wonder if IntelliJ is even recognizing it.

The last schema I gave a try came from this post [Unique constraint in XML Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717515/unique-constraint-in-xml-schema)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="http://www.brabantia.com/XMLSchema/ESBConfig"
        xmlns:tns="http://www.brabantia.com/XMLSchema/ESBConfig"
        elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <element name="authors">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="author" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="string"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
        <unique name="uniqueAuthor">
            <selector xpath="author"/>
            <field xpath="."/>
        </unique>
    </element>
</schema>
```

Which I used to generate the XML by IntelliJ.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<esb:authors xmlns:esb="http://www.brabantia.com/XMLSchema/ESBConfig">
  <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
  <esb:author>string</esb:author>
  <esb:author>string</esb:author>
  <esb:author>string</esb:author>
</esb:authors>
```

Which should show an error, but it doesn't.

In the `Generate Instance Document From Schema` wizard I have checked `Enable restriction check` and `Enable unique check`.

All other checks work, like enumeration and pattern.

Could someone tell me if this is something in the schema or something that is simply not supported in IntellJ?

Comment: Add `xmlns:esb="http://www.brabantia.com/XMLSchema/ESBConfig"` and change to `<selector xpath="esb:author"/>` in your schema

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `xmlns:esb="http://www.brabantia.com/XMLSchema/ESBConfig"` and change to `<selector xpath="esb:author"/> in your schema`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="http://www.brabantia.com/XMLSchema/ESBConfig"
        xmlns:esb="http://www.brabantia.com/XMLSchema/ESBConfig"
        elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <element name="authors">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="author" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="string"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
        <unique name="uniqueAuthor">
            <selector xpath="esb:author"/>
            <field xpath="."/>
        </unique>
    </element>
</schema>
```

Result:

[image: Validation result]